# Model returned from View does not have the value set in the view when call comes back to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to pass a query parameter value from HomeController to another controller called PasscodeVerificationController which renders a new view. This view has button called verify which takes a passcode from user and sends call back to action in PasscodeVerificationController, during this whole process I need to pass along query parameter but value set in Razor view gets lost when call comes to the action method

Following is view code

```cs
@model Test.Models.PasscodeVerificationModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("verify", "PasscodeVerification", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <h2>Enter your passcode here</h2>
    Test.Models.SignerModel signer = ViewBag.Signer;
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Passcode)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Passcode)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.signerModel)
    <input type="submit" value="Verify" />
}
```

Following is the controller code

```cs
    public class PasscodeVerificationController : Controller
    {
        [ActionName("passcode")]
        public ActionResult Index(SignerModel signer)
        {

           /*Here signer has the value and its being passed to view and I can 
           confirm in the view this value exists */
               ViewBag.Signer = signer;
               return View("~/Views/Passcode/Index.cshtml", new PasscodeVerificationModel { signerModel = signer});
        }

        [HttpPost()]
        [ActionName("verify")]
        public ActionResult Verify(PasscodeVerificationModel tokenVerificationModel)
        {
            /*Signer model value is always null :( :( */
            var signerModel = tokenVerificationModel.signerModel;

            if (tokenVerificationModel.Passcode == "1234")
            {
                if (signerModel == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(signerModel.ReturnUrl))
                {
                    return Content("No return url");
                }


                return Redirect(WebUtility.UrlDecode(signerModel.ReturnUrl));
            }
            else
            {
                return Content("Verification failed");
            }
         }
      }


    public class PasscodeVerificationModel
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(8, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 4)]
        public string Passcode { get; set; }

        public SignerModel signerModel { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: you would need to do a hidden for all the members of the singer model. passing the entire object to a hidden wont work

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks man this helped, do you want to add this as an answer and I will mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to do a hidden for all the members of the singer model that you want returned on post.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.signerModel.Property1)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.signerModel.Property2)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.signerModel.Property3)
<!-- ... -->
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.signerModel.PropertyN)
```

Passing the entire object to a hidden html helper wont work as it will just return a `ToString` of the object which wont populate/bind the model when the form is posted.